# On state-transition matrix and fundamental theorem of local theory of curves

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, curves, orthogonal-matrices

Lately I was faced by a problem and I can't think some way to solve it:

> Let $A(t)$ be an antisymmetryc matrix, for all $t \in I$. Prove that $\phi(t,t_{0})$ (the state-transition matrix) is an orthogonal matrix $\forall t \in I$ in the ODE
> $$
> u'(t)=A(t)u(t).
> $$

Then, one must prove, using this result, the fundamental theorem of local theory of curves, the same described by Manfredo.

I've tried to write $\phi(t,t_{0}) = \phi(t)(\phi(t_{0}))^{-1} = \phi(t_{0},t)$, but I can't related this to the transpose. Any help will be very appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $ϕ(t_0,t_0)=I_d$, which is, among other things, orthogonal. Now consider the evolution of the orthogonality condition
$$
\frac{d}{dt}[ϕ(t,t_0)^Tϕ(t,t_0)-I_d]=[A(t)ϕ(t,t_0)]^Tϕ(t,t_0)+ϕ(t,t_0)^T[A(t)ϕ(t,t_0)]
$$
and use the anti-symmetry of $A$.

Another approach to the same calculation is to take a fixed vector $C$ and compute the derivative of the norm square $\|ϕ(t,t_0)C\|_2^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I got some thoughts: First, there is some typo (missing the $T$ on the first element of the second term? Then, if the derivative is $0$, it is constant; how can I prove that it is $0$ (and so on, $\phi$ is ort.)?
Last but not least, do you have some idea on proving the theorem, or has some book or link where I can find something? Thanks again!

Comment: You get the constant from evaluating the expression at $t=t_0$. // Thanks, the copy-paste process was indeed incomplete.